# Marcação de espaços em branco - Atom

Tags: atom

Visualizei algumas vídeo aulas onde notei algumas pessoas utilizando marcação de espaços em branco do código com caracteres e achei bem interessante. 
Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe me informar como isso se chama e se possível como aplicar no editor de texto Atom.

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Você pode tentar entrar em configurações (`CTRL+,`), ir em Editor e selecionar a opção *Show Invisibles*.

Comment: Leo teria como colocar um pedacinho de um screenshot mostrando o recurso desejado, só para termos certeza do que se refere? Seria isso aqui? http://hmemcpy.com/2015/03/disabling-certain-invisibles-in-the-atom-editor/image.png

Comment: Exatamente isso. Utilizei os passos que o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse e deu certo, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta é uma prática útil quando você quer evitar que caracteres invisíveis estejam em seu código sem seu consentimento. Principalmente quando um trecho de código é copiado de outro lugar (um site, por exemplo).

> **Nota**: alguns termos descritos a seguir podem variar conforme a configuração de idioma do seu editor.

Para tal, basta entrar nas configurações do editor através do menu **Editar / Preferências** ou pelo atalho do teclado <kbd>CTRL + ,</kbd>.

[image: Configurações do Atom]

No menu de navegação, lado esquerdo da página, acesse a aba **Editor**.

[image: Aba Editor]

Desça até as configurações de caracteres invisíveis e selecione a opção **Exibir Invisíveis**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você ainda pode personalizar os caracteres que serão exibidos alterando as seguintes configurações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]